# How would I prove that this is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $Tr : R^
{n×n} → R$ denote the trace function on $n×n$ matrices
(i.e. the function that sums the diagonal entries of a matrix.)

How do I prove that $Tr$ is a linear transformation?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that something is a linear transformation, you must show that it distributes across sums and scalar multiplication, i.e. show that $\text{Tr}(A+B) = \text{Tr}(A) + \text{Tr}(B)$ and $\text{Tr}(\lambda A) = \lambda\text{Tr}(A)$.

In each case, I recommend writing out some arbitrary matrices and showing what the trace does to each. I.e., take: $$A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn} 
\end{array}\right] \hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt} B = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nn} 
\end{array}\right]$$ and see what the trace of each individually is, the trace of the sum is, and the trace of a scalar multiple of one is, and show that the trace "factors out" of each of those operations.